# grid view button asp.net c#

Tags: gridview

we want to accept only one record in gridview through accept button but in our code all requests are accepted if we are on last record.kindly let me know the problem in my code also provide the solution

protected void ChangeStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var context = new healthCareContext();

```
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        string str = btn.CommandName;

        var pemail = str;

        //////int row = GridView1.Rows.Count;
        ////GridView1.SelectedIndex =GridView1.Rows.Count;
        ////string mypemail = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;

        String status="Accepted";
        if (btn.Text == "Accepted")
            btn.Visible = false;
        string newStatus = "";
        if (btn.Text == "Accept")
        {
            newStatus = "Accepted";
            Response.Write("appointment has been Accepted and added in the database table 'appointments'.");

        }


        using (context)
        {
            var results = (from a in context.appointments where a.pemail == pemail select a);

            foreach (var b in results)
            {
                b.astatus = newStatus;
                //string signupName = b.name;
            }
            //int row = GridView1.Rows.Count;
            //GridView1.Selected
           // string mypemail = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["healthCareContext"].ConnectionString);

            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine(conn);
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT into appointments (astatus) values (@p1) where pemail==" + pemail + "), conn");
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", status);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            context.SaveChanges();

        }
        Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "0");
    }
```

the html markup

' onClick="ChangeStatus">
                            
        
        
        " SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [appointments]">

Comment: Possible post your `GridView`'s html mark-up.

Answer (score 0):

Probably pemail parameter in your LINQ select getting results is null when you select last row.

Comment: i need to get the value of the pemail of the current row in the gridview so tht i can add it in the linq query, but i dont know how to apply this functionality. Any help?

Comment: Why you didn't use 'pemail = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text'?

Comment: this is the exception.Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: So maybe last row is empty or have null values?

Answer (score 0):

html markup

' onClick="ChangeStatus">
                            
        
        
        " SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [appointments]">